# How to Set Timer Countdown in Flutter for 30 Second with OnPressed FAB Button?

Tags: android, dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

Currently, I have write codes for making up the counter app with two buttons. 1 raised button to reset and one fab button for increment counter.

is it possible to add the countdown timer to implement on FAB button? When FAB button clicks 20-second countdown timer start.

Also, I have found below thread for the same type of function implement. But I don't where to put codes in my app to implement countdown work on FAB button.

[How to make a countdown in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51467088/how-to-make-a-countdown-in-flutter)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Counter App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Counter App'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  int _counter = 0;
  AnimationController controller;
  bool _isButtonDisabled;

  Duration get duration => controller.duration * controller.value;

  bool get expired => duration.inSeconds == 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 20),
    );

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'number $_counter added',
            ),
            AnimatedBuilder(
                animation: controller,
                builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                  return new Text(
                    '${duration.inSeconds}',
                    style: new TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 50.0,
                    ),
                  );
                }),
            new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                new RaisedButton(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      controller.reset();
                      _counter = 0;
                    });
                  },
                  child: new Text("Reset"),
                ),
                new RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () => setState(() {
                    controller.reverse(from: 1);
                  }),
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  color: Colors.purple,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  child: new Text(
                    "Start",
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Container(
          height: 50.0,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => setState(() {
          _counter++;
        }),
        tooltip: 'Increment Counter',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'dart:async';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Counter App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Counter App'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  int _counter = 0;
  AnimationController controller;

  Duration get duration => controller.duration * controller.value;

  bool get expired => duration.inSeconds == 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 20),
    );

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: controller,
            builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
              return new Text(
                '${duration.inSeconds}',
                style: new TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 50.0,
                ),
              );
            }),
            new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                new RaisedButton(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      controller.reset();
                    });
                  },
                  child: new Text("Reset"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Container(
          height: 50.0,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => setState(() {

          controller.reverse(from: 1);
            }),
        tooltip: 'Increment Counter',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Following Error Coming. 

I/flutter ( 5238): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 5238): The following assertion was thrown building MyHomePage(dirty, state: _MyHomePageState#54b3a):
I/flutter ( 5238): 'package:flutter/src/widgets/transitions.dart': Failed assertion: line 43 pos 15: 'listenable !=
I/flutter ( 5238): null': is not true.

Comment: it is working on my side, are you sure you added everything, did you add the initState

Comment: Thank you its work, Use clean and restart the application successfully.

Comment: Need little more help that, After bool get expired to 0 seconds. Condition 1) how can i make disabled FAB counter button after complete counter time 20 seconds.  Condition 2) So, when user click reset then FAB will show enable to press.

Comment: you need to disable the fab button when the timer is elapsing or when the timer finishes??

Comment: When timer is finished.

Comment: when the timer finishes,expired will be false, so when the user presses on the fab check if the value of expires is false, when it false, don't do anything. When reset is clicked, make the value of expired to false, which will enable the fab again

Comment: I have updated the code in my question. you can try this code and you will get the idea how counter is still active after finished timer of 20 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

you can use anywhere this code.

```
Timer(Duration(seconds: 30), () {
      //checkFirstSeen(); your logic
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is a method called startResendTimer written in Dart, likely part of a Flutter application. It sets up a timer to resend an OTP (one-time password) after a certain duration. Here's an interpretation of how this code could be used in a story related to a Stack Overflow scenario:

```
     - int _resendTimeout = 60; // Resend timeout in seconds
                 Timer? _resendTimer;
                 bool _isTimerRunning = false;
       
       
       
       
             @override
             void initState() {
               initPlatformState();
               super.initState();
             }
           
       
       
             @override
             void dispose() {
               _resendTimer?.cancel();
               super.dispose();
             }
           
             void startResendTimer() {
               setState(() {
                 _isTimerRunning = true;
                 _resendTimeout = 60;
               });
           
               _resendTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
                 if (_resendTimeout > 0) {
                   setState(() {
                     _resendTimeout--;
                   });
                 } else {
                   setState(() {
                     otpSent = false;
                     _isTimerRunning = false;
                   });
                   _resendTimer?.cancel();
                 }
               });
             }




 Text(
otpSent ? 'Resend OTP $_resendTimeout' : 'Send OTP', 
 style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, 
 color: otpSent ? HexColor(HexColor.primaryColor) : HexColor(HexColor.black),
 fontFamily: 'lato_bold',
 decoration: TextDecoration.none,
  ),
 )
```